# How separating Lists with Headers in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, navigation-drawer

I am trying that add section `separator` header for `ListView` in `drawerLayout` but i can not see `separators` and i just see titles.

This my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    public Cursor cursor;
    public Cursor cursorsex;
    public ArrayList<String> array;
    public ArrayList<String> arraysex;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter ;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdaptersex ;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ListView mDrawerListsex;
.....
Connection to sqlite
.....
        sql = db.openDataBase();
        cursor = sql.rawQuery("SELECT Title FROM WebSite_CategoryBack WHERE ParentID=0;", null);
        array = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            Titel_Drawer = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Title"));
            array.add(Titel_Drawer);
        }
        cursor.close();


        cursorsex = sql.rawQuery("SELECT Title FROM WebSite_CategoryBack WHERE ParentID=0;", null);
        arraysex = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(cursorsex.moveToNext()){
            Titel_Drawer = cursorsex.getString(cursorsex.getColumnIndex("Comment"));
            arraysex.add(Titel_Drawer);
        }
        cursorsex.close();


        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        mDrawerListsex = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.sex);


        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_list,R.id.textView, array);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter( listAdapter );

        listAdaptersex = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.xxx,R.id.xxx, arraysex);
        mDrawerListsex.setAdapter( listAdaptersex );
   }
}
```

This is `xxx.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/xxx"/>
```

This is `drawer_list.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/textView"/>
```

This is `activity_main.xml`:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="start">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/prof"
            android:background="@drawable/drawer_title_shape" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->

    <ir.makarem.extentions.ClearableEditText
        android:id="@+id/SearchEdittxt"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="35dip"
        android:background="@drawable/textlines"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:hint="@string/action_search" />

    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:background="#FFDDDDDD"/>


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/sex"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:background="#FFDDDDDD"/>


</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

For example i need to see look like this photo.
[image: Sample]

I add two `TextView` for Title and two `ListView`.

Comment: Ugly code. Try to separate your queries from your layout code.

Comment: you have to add section header listview for this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you have to use section header listview  to achieve this functionality

Refrence link [Section header listview](http://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/)

Answer (score -1):

You need to **set a divider** for your `ListView`: (code example)

```
// white color for example
int[] clr = {0, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0};
listView.setDivider(new GradientDrawable(Orientation.RIGHT_LEFT, clr));
listView.setDividerHeight(1); // set your desired height
```

Or set the divider in .xml:

```
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#FFFFFF"
        android:dividerHeight="2px" >
    </ListView>
```

Comment: Hi @Philipp Jahoda .I have two ListView in my project i should use witch one ListView for setDivider ?

Comment: That is entirely up to you. If you want a ListView to have a divider, you set one, if not, you don't. I dont really get your question.